# Is there an American Community Survey dataset that provides individual-level data at the census tract level?

Tags: data-request, us-census

I am hoping to estimate the number of five year-olds below various poverty thresholds by census tract. The ACS definitely asks these questions individually, but no data source I've found can provide this exact statistic. What I've tried:

- [American Fact Finder](http://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/searchresults.xhtml?refresh=t): Can produce summary tables of *either* estimated number of five year-olds by census tract *or* estimated number of individuals below poverty thresholds by census tract, but not a combination of the two. This goes for their online interface, their summary file, and FTP as far as I can tell.
- [IPUMS](https://usa.ipums.org/usa/): Provides individual-level data that allows for such a combination of variables, but does not provide it at lower than the PUMA geographic level.

Does anyone know of a source that could provide me with such data? If it matters, I'm looking at 2015 5-year estimates.

Comment: hi, definitely not available as microdata.  if you cannot find the numbers in american fact finder, your alternative is probably https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/data/custom-tables.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question: [N](https://www.census.gov/history/www/reference/privacy_confidentiality/title_26_us_code_1.html)[o](https://www.census.gov/history/www/reference/privacy_confidentiality/title_13_us_code.html), there is no *open data* version of the American Community Survey with PII (Personally Identifiable Information).

As for your original query, [Table B17001](https://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/15_5YR/B17001/0400000US01.14000|0400000US02.14000|0400000US04.14000), does provide the age breakdown between those below the statistical poverty threshold and those at or above the statistical poverty threshold.

The AFF link I provided is a modifiable link through something the Census Bureau calls [deep linking](https://factfinder.census.gov/files/AFF_deep_linking_guide.pdf). My suggestion is to figure out which state's Census Tracts you'll want, figure out the FIPS code for that/those state(s), and modify the link. You'll need to create at least two since the Census Bureau provides a limit on geographies per request if you're doing a nationwide download (last I checked the limit was 50,000 and there are ~74,000 Census Tracts).

Answer (score 2):

If you are affiliated with academia, you can get to the detailed PII data through the Census Research Data Centers (https://www.census.gov/about/adrm/fsrdc/locations.html). They operate at an academic pace -- it takes 6-9 months to get your request considered.